# Properly Converting from UTM to Lat/Long with gdalwarp

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp

I have a file in GeoTiff format in UTM coordinates.  I convert the file to LatLong, then back to UTM, and the coordinates aren't what I started with.  I have the printout of the process below.

`gdalsrsinfo 6b6.tif` produces the following:

```
PROJ.4 : '+proj=utm +zone=16 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs '

OGC WKT :
PROJCS["NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_16N",
    GEOGCS["NAD83",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010002,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-87],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","26916"]]
```

`gdalwarp -t_srs '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs' 6b6.tif output.tif`

```
gdalinfo output.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: output.tif
Size is 1384, 1379
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-86.750459052801645,40.250430422810176)
Pixel Size = (0.000091263992370,-0.000091263992370)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  BandDefinitionKeyword=NONE
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -86.7504591,  40.2504304) ( 86d45' 1.65"W, 40d15' 1.55"N)
Lower Left  ( -86.7504591,  40.1245774) ( 86d45' 1.65"W, 40d 7'28.48"N)
Upper Right ( -86.6241497,  40.2504304) ( 86d37'26.94"W, 40d15' 1.55"N)
Lower Right ( -86.6241497,  40.1245774) ( 86d37'26.94"W, 40d 7'28.48"N)
Center      ( -86.6873044,  40.1875039) ( 86d41'14.30"W, 40d11'15.01"N)
Band 1 Block=1384x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-3.4028234663852886e+38
  Metadata:
    RepresentationType=ATHEMATIC
```

and then converting back, `gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:26916 output.tif back.tif`

```
gdalinfo back.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: back.tif
Size is 1197, 1552
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["NAD83 / UTM zone 16N",
    GEOGCS["NAD83",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010002,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-87],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","26916"]]
Origin = (521222.733228680794127,4455620.891041336581111)
Pixel Size = (9.022681340919917,-9.022681340919917)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  BandDefinitionKeyword=NONE
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  521222.733, 4455620.891) ( 86d45' 1.65"W, 40d15' 2.78"N)
Lower Left  (  521222.733, 4441617.690) ( 86d45' 3.31"W, 40d 7'28.60"N)
Upper Right (  532022.883, 4455620.891) ( 86d37'24.49"W, 40d15' 1.54"N)
Lower Right (  532022.883, 4441617.690) ( 86d37'27.00"W, 40d 7'27.37"N)
Center      (  526622.808, 4448619.290) ( 86d41'14.11"W, 40d11'15.14"N)
Band 1 Block=1197x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-3.4028234663852886e+38
  Metadata:
    RepresentationType=ATHEMATIC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to post the input raster (in UTM) information too so a true before-and-after comparison can be made.

Representing data using lat/lon in a raster means using a Plate Carree-like projection and treating the decimal degree values as if they're linear measures. UTM data is often 'tilted' in comparison so data is resampled. There'll be 'no data' values on the edges of the rasters so you can't trust the report extents exactly.

Comment: In other words, the first step warps and rotates the image and I guess that when you open the image you will see black nodata slivers at the corners. Your next command is warping and rotating again this new image including the slivers that were introduced in the process and probably adds even more nodata area into the corners. Open images into a viewer for getting visual feedback.